# How to initiate server side message in WebSockets Java?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I'm using the javax.websocket API in Java. I am using a Jetty server and Javascript for the client. How do I initiate sendMessage from the server?

Details: Am using a jetty-maven-plugin 9.4.8.v20171121.

Server-side dependencies: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket - websocket-server and javax-websocket-server-impl.

Here's my server code:

```
package com.trice.server.web;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/WebSocketTestServlet")
public class WebSocketTestServlet {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(){
        System.out.println("Open Connection ...");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){
        System.out.println("Close Connection ...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message){
        System.out.println("Message from the client: " + message);
        String echoMsg = "Echo from the server : " + message;
        return echoMsg;
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And client code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Tomcat WebSocket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="message" type="text">
        <input onclick="wsSendMessage();" value="Echo" type="button">
        <input onclick="wsCloseConnection();" value="Disconnect" type="button">
    </form>
    <br>
    <textarea id="echoText" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketTestServlet");
        var echoText = document.getElementById("echoText");
        echoText.value = "";
        var message = document.getElementById("message");
        webSocket.onopen = function(message){ wsOpen(message);};
        webSocket.onmessage = function(message){ wsGetMessage(message);};
        webSocket.onclose = function(message){ wsClose(message);};
        webSocket.onerror = function(message){ wsError(message);};
        function wsOpen(message){
            echoText.value += "Connected ... \n";
        }
        function wsSendMessage(){
            webSocket.send(message.value);
            echoText.value += "Message sent to the server : " + message.value + "\n";
            message.value = "";
        }
        function wsCloseConnection(){
            webSocket.close();
        }
        function wsGetMessage(message){
            echoText.value += "Message received from to the server : " + message.data + "\n";
        }
        function wsClose(message){
            echoText.value += "Disconnect ... \n";
            console.log("disconnect", message);
        }

        function wsError(message){
            echoText.value += "Error \n";
            console.log("error", message);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Reference [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/)

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Your question misses some information: on what condition do you want to send a message? Upon another message received? Upon an event? Anyway, for a basic answer, a [link to a tutorial (section 4.4)](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jetty/jetty-websocket-example/) will do: `session.getBasicRemote().sendText(“yahooo!”);`

Comment: I wanted to send a message when an event occurred.

Comment: As per your answer, it was a simple stuff... By the way, if you plan to use CDI events (`@Observes`) in your `ServerEndpoint`, please be aware that if no websocket client is connected, you may encounter some issues. In my project, we use a session handler class to handle CDI events

Comment: In my limited experience, I haven't come across CDI events...can you please elaborate? Any specific examples that can throw some light on the matter will be great...Thanks

Comment: If you're free, I'll rather talk in a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162727/discussion-between-al1-and-raksheetbhat (I'm new to chat...)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Went through it. Haven't planned to use CDI events yet, but if the need arises, will definitely come back here as a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a very easy answer to my question. All I needed to do was:

```
session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Some string");
```

Comment: How do you get the session object?? @raksheetbhat

Comment: Define a websocket ServerEndpoint which defines callback methods - `@OnOpen public void onOpen(Session wsSession, @PathParam("param") final String param)` which gives you a websocket.session object.

Comment: I had looked at the article previously. In that sending of a message to user 2 is initiated by receiving of a message from user 2. So it's not purely initiated from server side. In my case, it's like after completion of asynchronous batch job, i need to send a message to the browser. In this case how can we get the session?

Comment: You can maintain a list of user sessions server side, and retrieve those sessions when you need to send a message to all active users. Or maintain a hashmap with userid, so you can retrieve sessions for particular users.